# Performance Problems Started - How to Debug (Ubuntu + Django/Python)

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, performance, vps, django

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 10.10, with a Django application running on top of it (MySQL database, Redis datastore, apache + mod_wsgi in daemon mode).

Over the last few days, we've been experiencing serious performance issues, with the server taking 1 minute+ to return a response.

This has just started happening over the past few days, before that we had no problems.

`top` says I'm using only 4-5% of my CPU, `free -m` says I have over 700mb ram free.

What should my next steps be to understanding and solving the problem?

Answer (score 0):

next step is watch your bdd : 
try to enable slow queries logs or check response time with django debug sql to identify the bottlenecks

next step may be I/O ..